# specific menu with specific data for each object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a page where you can create "documents" that are divs with specific properties.
For now I thought about `name` & `color`.

First, when you click in the body, you can create a document that is called "something+i" (i is its ID) then, when you click a specific document you can access a menu to edit its color and its name.
finally when you close the menu by clicking `OK` the specific `document` is updated.

Do you have any idea on how to do that?
Thanks a lot for the help.

```js
var i = 1;
$(function(){
    $(document.body).click(function(e){
        var div =  $("<div />", { "class":"document", id:"document"+i })
            .css({
                "left": e.pageX + 'px',
                "top": e.pageY + 'px'
            })
             .append($( "<p>document</p>")+i )
            .appendTo(document.body);
                
  $('.document').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
      $('.menu').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
      document.querySelector(".document").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "block";
});
     document.querySelector(".validate").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "none";
}); 
      
      i++;
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}
.document {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
  resize:both;
  overflow: auto;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.2rem black);
}

.menu{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
  <div class="menu">
    <li><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="10" placeholder="name"></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="color" name="color" size="10" placeholder="color"></li>
    
    <button class ="validate">OK</button>
    </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on  `document` first check if there is any menu exist with the id which is clicked if there is `show` that menu else create new menu .You can use `clone` to create new menu and then add `data-id` to it and append them under some divs .

Then , when `ok` button is clicked simply use `$(this).closest(".menu_copy").hide();` to hide the menu .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var i = 1;
$(function() {
  $(document.body).click(function(e) {
    var subject = $(".menu_copy")
    //check if target click doesn't have class document && not inside menu_copy
    if ((!$(event.target).hasClass('document')) && (!subject.has(e.target).length)) {

      var div = $("<div />", {
          "class": "document",
          id: "document" + i
        })
        .css({
          "left": e.pageX + 'px',
          "top": e.pageY + 'px'
        })
        .append($("<p>document</p>") + i)
        .appendTo(document.body);
      i++;
    }
  });

  //onclick of document
  $(document).on('click', '.document', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); //get id
    //check if there is any div with data-id
    if ($("[data-id =" + id + " ]").length > 0) {
      $("[data-id =" + id + " ]").show() //show it
    } else {
      //create new menu 
      var clone_menu = $(".menu_copy:first").clone();
      $(clone_menu).attr("data-id", $(this).attr("id"))
      $(clone_menu).css("display", "block")
      $(clone_menu).appendTo(".docs"); //append inside docs
    }
  });
  //if ok is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '.validate', function(event) {
  //get color and name
    var name = $(this).closest(".menu_copy").find("input[name='name']").val();
    var color = $(this).closest(".menu_copy").find("input[name='color']").val();
    var data_id = $(this).closest(".menu_copy").attr("data-id")
    $("#" + data_id).text(name);//add name
    $("#" + data_id).css("color", color);//apply color
    $(this).closest(".menu_copy").hide(); //hide the menu
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.document {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.2rem black);
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="menu_copy" style="display:none">
    <li><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="10" placeholder="name"></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="color" name="color" size="10" placeholder="color"></li>

    <button class="validate">OK</button>
  </div>

  <!--added this divs new menus will go inside this -->
  <div class="docs"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, its seems to be working on your demo.
My concern would be how to apply the data in the input options to the specific `document` if I type yellow for object one, it changes the color to yellow.

Comment: You mean when user type color yellow then that object div color should change to yellow? Between you didn't mention this in your question ?

Comment: yep!
that's was my original idea.
Each `document` as an id (`var i`) and you can click them to edit them individually.
So you can change the `name` input for `document 1` and it display its name (instead of [object] and edit the color of this specific `document`

Comment: Updated have a look .